# Class D Amplifier with Inverting Logic

Tags: amplifier, class-d

If a class D amplifier had an additional logic input which was used to indicate that the amplifier's output should be inverted, could one use this signal to swap the logic of amplifier's switches so that the amplifier's output was inverted?

Where inverting results in a signal that has +x on the input to the amplifier with a signal that has -x on the output.

Is this a "thing" with existing terminology surrounding it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, to be honest. The output isn't a logic signal, it's an analog audio signal. Do you want to invert the phase of the audio using a logic input on an integrated amplifier chip, or something else?

Comment: For normal (class A, B) amplifiers you would invert the output to use two to make a bridge amplifier (Which gives four times the output power) . I have never looked into class D but I would suspect you can't do that without seriously adapting the output filter.

Comment: In theory this is logically true. In practise no, because we need to know prop delay, dead-time impedance if switch and reactance of everything.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this is logically true. In practise no, because we need to know prop delay, dead-time (!) , impedance of commutation switches , load and reactance of everything.

This thing is called a “Half-Bridge” also used in Buck-Boost SMPS and have many specific parameters for each load and power range for specs.

Then for differential high power from a low voltage to a woofer, one can use a full-bridge with differential output. But for low DCR motors and surge battery chargers and other nonlinear surge current loads, use RdsOn=< 10% of Motor DCR or <= 1% of rated V/I for starting choice for loss vs cost. But too low and Q rises with ringing.

It is most important to understand the power loss budget with RdsOn, DCR of chokes, ESR of caps and low Q for light loaded LC filters that  can resonate on harmonics. Examine transfer functions on a simulator looking for spurious simulated resonances then verify with the best layout practices.

Comment: Could you make the sentence "but for low crime motors..." a complete thought?